# Controlling floating point's error

Tags: floating-point

I'm trying to manage floating point's error by only using the 2 most significant values after the period:

```
static float lowerPrecision(float highPrecisionFloat)
{
    char buff[8] = {0};
    sprintf(buff, "%.2f", highPrecisionFloat);
    float lowerPrecisionFloat = atof(buff);
    return lowerPrecisionFloat;
}

void main(void)
{
    float highPrecisionFloat = 127 / 100.0;
    printf("highPrecisionFloat: %.12f\n", highPrecisionFloat);
    float lowerPrecisionFloat = lowerPrecision(highPrecisionFloat);
    printf("lowerPrecisionFloat: %.12f\n", lowerPrecisionFloat);
}
```

Returns:

```
highPrecisionFloat: 1.269999980927
lowerPrecisionFloat: 1.269999980927
```

Why is my implementation isn't working (i assume it's atof's fault) and is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.269999980927` are the first digits of the decimal representation of the closest float to 127/100. You cannot round it to something closer to 127/100.

You **can** round many `float` values to one of a set of chosen representatives. This is a valid strategy in some cases for dealing with floating-point approximations, and this is what your function `lowerPrecision` does (albeit inefficiently and with interesting risks of stack overflow). But that function **cannot** return a `float` representing 127/100, because that float does not exist.

Binary floating-point types use a binary representation in which 1/10 and 127/10 cannot be represented exactly with any number of fractional digits. You could choose your representatives as those that use at most 8 binary digits (instead of two decimal ones), or you can keep your function `lowerPrecision` as written, but either way, no function that you can write will return a float that represents 127/100 exactly.

You could make the binary representation of floating-point types much more visceral by using the [hexadecimal format](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/) `%a` for input and output of floating-point values. That would help [make it intuitive](http://ideone.com/ENw26p) that some simple decimal values cannot be represented exactly.